# Имена полей Pojo объекта

Tags: java, json

Почему `objectMapper` не видит сеттеров полей `Pojo` объекта?

Класс `User`

```
    public class User {
        private String ID;
        private boolean ACTIVE;
        private String UF_PHONE_INNER;

        public String getID() {
            return ID;
        }

        public void setID(String ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
... и т.д.
```

Класс `Users`

```
public class Users {
    private User[] result;

    public User[] getUsers() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(User[] result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
и т.д....
```

Разбираю `JSON`

```
log.debug("jsonString is {}",jsonString);
users.setResult(objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Users.class).getUsers());
```

Получаю:

```
DEBUG log:71 - jsonString is {"result":[{"ID":"1","ACTIVE":true,...
WARN  log:81 - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ID" (class ru.bityard.bitrix24.User), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "id", "active", "uf_PHONE_INNER"])
```

Я понять не могу, почему он видит `id` вместо `ID` ???
У меня впечатление, что парсер, воспринимает поле `ID` как объект...

Comment: `ID` у вас `String` и написано в верхнем регистре. Советовал бы Вам для начала изучить чекстайл языка `Java`. Название `final` поля пишется в верхнем регистре, но никак не обычное поле. Вам даже ошибка подсказывает `not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "id", "active", "uf_PHONE_INNER"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson видя метод `setID` считает что поле будет называться `iD`. Добавьте аннотацию `@JsonProperty` и назовите поля в стиле java

```
public class User {
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло )